# Will google glass be able to run normal android apps?

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm currently working on a heads up display project for a different hardware, but it's Android based. I'm a bit concerned that Google might require using only `mirror api` to develop for Google Glass. Anybody familiar with the product knows if you can run Java-based Android apps on it?

Comment: yes it is able to run Android apps with minor change or no change at all as its running Android 4.0.4 at core. Hope it would help. Cheers!!